# A lazy function which calculates multiplication only when it feels like - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I recently came up with this question where there was this piece of function given:

```
function randMulti(a,b) {
  if(Math.random() < 0.1) {
    return a*b;
  } else {
    throw new MultiError("Error Occurred");
  }
}
```

The task was to **call** this **function** until we get the result.
By Result I mean result of multiplication, as `randMulti` has a condition to throw error, which is based on Math.Random, so it might get fail certain times,  Task is to call it until we get the multiplication result.

to achieve this, I took a **flag** and ran a **while** loop **until** I got the result.

RESTRICTION: We can change `randMulti` function. Throwing error is mandatory.

QUESTION: Is below solution is an acceptable solution for this case, or is there any good way of achieving the same result?

Here is the complete code with JSFiddle Link:
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7d6gk8pm/)

```js
class MultiError extends Error{}

function randMulti(a,b) {
  if(Math.random() < 0.1) {
    return a*b;
  } else {
    throw new MultiError("Error Occurred");
  }
}

function randExecuter(fn) {
    return function(a,b) {
    let allOK = false;
    let res = '';
    while(!allOK) {
      try {
        res = fn(a,b);
        allOK = true;
      } catch(e) {
         console.error(e);
      }
    }
    
    return res;
  }
}

let multiply = randExecuter(randMulti);

const result = multiply(7,5);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what kind of error you have out of memory or memory leak, what were the exact error?

Comment: a good solution to what?

Comment: @mzaifquraishi we can skip the what part. I am more curious to know if there is any better solution.

Comment: @KevinB a good solution to call this function until we get the result. 

I have done it using taking a flag and using while loop. SO just curious to know if this is acceptable solution for this proble,

Comment: I mean... that's not really for us to decide is it? Is your team expecting approval from random SO users to decide whether or not to move forward?

Comment: @KevinB got it, but any comment of yours on the solution? or if you have to solve this problem then will you also use the same way or do you have something else in your mind.

Comment: @KevinB NO Kevin, this question was asked in one of the interview I was giving.

Comment: *"The task was to call this function until we get the result."* what result? not an error?

Comment: @KevinB result of multiplication, as `randMulti` has a condition to throw error, which is based on Math.Random, so it might get fail certain times,  Task is to call it until we get the multiplication result.

Comment: Then what other method would you expect to have, other than, calling it till you don't get an error?

Comment: @KevinB yes Kevin

Answer (score 2):

*Much* simpler by only calling the function in a try/catch in an infinite loop:

```js
class MultiError extends Error{}

function randMulti(a,b) {
  if(Math.random() < 0.1) {
    return a*b;
  } else {
    throw new MultiError("Error Occurred");
  }
}

function randExecuter(fn) {
  return function() {
    while(true) {
      try {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      } catch(e) { 
        console.error("error, retrying");
      }
    }
  }
}

let multiply = randExecuter(randMulti);

const result = multiply(7,5);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; )
```

The `return` statement will immediately terminate the function when executed. If the code throws an error, it does not reach the `return` and instead loops over from the start.

Using [`Function#apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) as `.apply(this, arguments)` will ensure that `fn` is called *exactly* the same as it would be otherwise - using the same value for `this` as well as the same arguments. This way, it will also work on methods in objects:

```js
class MultiError extends Error{}

const MyMath = {
  constantMultiplier: 3, 
  randMulti(a,b) {
    if(Math.random() < 0.1) {
      return a*b*this.constantMultiplier;
    } else {
      throw new MultiError("Error Occurred");
    }
  }
}

function randExecuter(fn) {
  return function() {
    while(true) {
      try {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      } catch(e) { 
        console.error("error, retrying");
      }
    }
  }
}

MyMath.multiply = randExecuter(MyMath.randMulti);

const result = MyMath.multiply(7,5);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; )
```

---

A possible improvement would be to avoid endless loops. The number of times the function call is retried can be limited, just in case:

```
function randExecuter(fn, maxRetries = 100) {
  return function() {
    while(--maxRetries > 0) {
      try {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      } catch(e) { 
        console.error("error, retrying");
      }
    }

    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

This will try calling the function `maxRetries - 1` times in a `try`/`catch` and then call it one last time outside the block. This way if it still does throw, the caller can receive the error.

Example usage:

```js
function randExecuter(fn, maxRetries = 100) {
  return function() {
    while(--maxRetries > 0) {
      try {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      } catch(e) { 
        console.error("error, retrying");
      }
    }

    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

function alwaysThrows() {
  throw new Error("boom");
}
const multiply = randExecuter(alwaysThrows, 5);
const result = multiply(7,5);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; )
```

If for whatever reason it does need to retry forever, then pass `Infinity` as a second parameter which means it will never stop: `randExecuter(someFn, Infinity)`

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, it makes more sense.